# PDF-catalogue run over by Emojis

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser

I am managing the website filuren.dk, and we run a pdf-based catalogue, which is driven purely by JavaScript. No problem with this. However, our client have had customers experiencing that the pdf catalogue, has been run over by emojis as seen on the pictures.

I haven't been able to recreate the issue myself, so i have absolutely no idea how to fix it and what to do here. Can anybody enlighten me?

NB: It only happens on certain iPads..

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAcLe.jpg)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiVPW.jpg)

Comment: Are you generating the PDFs in your JavaScript?

Comment: No. The PDF is created before, as seen here: http://filuren.dk/FlipBook/program-efteraar-2017-filuren.html

Comment: How are you streaming/downloading it? So far this doesn't seem to be related to programming at all.

Comment: I can't seem to find out if this problem is actually caused by the customer's own setting on his/her iPad.. Thanks for the interest so far. I am trying to get more knowledge before I act any further.

Answer (score 0):

this is what people use to add imges,

```
.this.getField('imageField').importImage('path_to_img');
```

instead of images you can add custom Emojis(.svg or something)

like this:

```
var f = this.getField("btnImage");
f.buttonSetCaption("Title");
  if (f.buttonImportIcon("/C/image.pdf") == 0){  // if 0 == no error
      f.buttonImportIcon("/C/image.pdf");
  }
```

you can find the full discussion at Adobe forums on Insert an image into pdf (Adobe Acrobat Pro DC) using javascript.
https://forums.adobe.com/message/8694023#8694023

Comment: I am not sure this is what i am looking for. I need to make sure that those emojis doesn't come up and interrupt the experience for the customers.